# Mysql database writes and file writes

Tags: c++, mysql, file

I have a program which writes data to mysql database and also huge amounts of logs to a file.. i have noticed that if i give huge amounts of data as input to the program, i.e data that creates logs as big as 70GB and mysql database table count(*), of the table that i use, to >1,000,000 entries, the whole programme slows down after some time..

But when initially the reports were collected at the rate of around 1000/min but the same becomes < 400/min wen the data is as i said before. Is this the database writes or the file writes that makes the program slower?

The logs are just cout from my program that are redirected to a file. No buffering is done there.

Comment: Do you save to a file or you send the data to the database?

Comment: What is the difference between the two cases (besides the speed)? It's not clear at all.

Comment: What schema are you using to store the logs?

Comment: i mean i do them simultaneously.... i put data to table and i output success/failure with some extra details for debugging...

Comment: How many lines are you writing to the database with each INSERT?

Comment: each line in my input is inserted into the database as an entry. so if my input has 10 lines, it uses 10 inserts.

Comment: in this case it has >1,000,000 input lines.

Comment: @jay : u want me to give you the table details??

Comment: @Prasanth: This is certainly one reason for slowness. Try doing `INSERT`s in bunches of 10 or 100 of them and see what happens. I mean writing 10 or 100 rows with every `INSERT`.

Comment: Maybe you should try to only call a insert statement when you have around 1000 lines, if as you said you collect around 1000 lines per minute.

Comment: @João Augusto : what about the log file?? will huge size of the log file slow down consequent writes to the file?

Comment: @Prasanth Madhavan: I believe your biggest problem here is calling the INSERT statement. If you aren't opening and closing the file every time you write I don't think the problem is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to test for this.

If you create a `blackhole` table, MySQL will pretend to do everything but never really write any data to file.

1. create table(s) just like your
   normal table(s),
2. Make a copy of the logs.
3. Now write to the blackhole database just like you would in the real database.

If it's much faster it's MySQL giving you grief.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html